# Db2 for I: Cpyf *nochk emulation

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

In the IBM i system there's a way to copy a from a structured file to one without structure using `Cpyf *nochk`.

How can it be done with sql?

Answer (score 1):

The answer may be "You can't", not if you are using DDL defined tables anyway. The problem is that `*NOCHK` just dumps data into the file like a flat file. Files defined with `CRTPF`, whether they have source, or are program defined, don't care about bad data until read time, so they can contain bad data. In fact you can even read bad data out of a file if you use a program definition for that file.

But, an SQL Table (one defined using DDL) cannot contain bad data. No matter how you write it, the database validates the data at write time. Even the `*NOCHK` option of the `CPYF` command cannot coerce bad data into an SQL table.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't an easy way

Closest would be to just build a big character string using CONCAT...

```
insert into flatfile
 select mycharfld1
        concat cast(myvchar as char(20))
        concat digits(zonedFld3)
  from mytable
```

That works for fixed length, varchar (if casted to char) and zoned decimal...

Packed decimal would be problematic..

I've seen user defined functions that can return the binary character string that make up a packed decimal...but it's very ugly

I question why you think you need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  QSYS2.QCMDEXC stored procedure to execute OS commands.

Example:

call qsys2.qcmdexc ( 'CPYF FROMFILE(QTEMP/FILE1) TOFILE(QTEMP/FILE2) MBROPT(*replace) FMTOPT(*NOCHK)' )